# How to check RequestPermissions in ios?

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins

I need to access photos and maps in my application.so I have added the corresponding feature in plist file.But I need to check whether the request has been allowed or denied.Am not getting how to do it please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check explicitly for different types of Permission like Images/Video, Location, Contact List etc.

1. Images/Videos/Audios/Documents etc

   ```
   NSString *mediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo;
   AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:mediaType];
   if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
   {
      // do your logic
   } else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied)
   {
        // denied
       [self showSettingsAlert:@"Previously you have denied"];
   } else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
   {
       // restricted, normally won't happen
      [self showSettingsAlert:@"You have revoke"];
   } else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
   {
       // not determined?!
       [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:mediaType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted)
       {
            if(granted)
            {
                [self openVideoPicker:buttonIndex];
            } else
            {
                [self showSettingsAlert:@"You have denied"];
            }
       }];
   } else
   {
       [self showSettingsAlert:@"You have revoke"];
   }
   ```

Just change AVMediaTypes according to your requirement.

1. Mobile Contact List

   ```
   CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
   if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
   {
        //Show Alert Access Denied
        return;
   }

   CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
   [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
         // make sure the user granted us access
         if (!granted)
         {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 //Show Alert Access Denied
                 return;
    }

    BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop)
    {
        // build array of contacts
        NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSError *fetchError;
        CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName], CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey]];
        [contacts addObject:contact];
    }];
    if (!success)
    {
        [UIUtil showWarningAlert:fetchError.localizedDescription onController:self];
        return;
    }
   ```

   Put this code in your function which will handle such permission validations.
2. For Location you have to implement **CLLocationManagerDelegate** and these two functions will give you location information.

   ```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
   {
       currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
       [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

       latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
       longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
   }

   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
        if (error.domain == kCLErrorDomain && error.code == kCLErrorDenied)
        {
            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            [self showSettingsAlert:@"You have denied Location Permission"];
        }
   }
   ```

Don't forget to import package appropriate packages for these codes.

Answer (score 0):

for photo picker you can use

```
UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) or .camera
```

and for loaction you can use

```
CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied
```

and don't forget to import corelocation